# problem with Drop-Down Menu in jQuery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

why `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` does not work true on my menu?
They are repeated several times with `mouseover()`.

see you: [jsfiddle-my codes](http://jsfiddle.net/5KEnp/)

```
$('#nav li').mouseover(function() {
        $('#nav li ul li').slideDown();
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $('#nav li ul li').slideUp();
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5KEnp/4/

```
$('#nav > li').mouseenter(function() {
    $('ul li', this).stop(true, true).slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('ul li', this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) (a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`) instead, and change your selector:

```
$('#nav > li').hover(function() {
    $('#nav li ul li').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $('#nav li ul li').slideUp();
})
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/jdsGx/

Previously, the events were bound to all `li`s under `#nav`. I think you just want direct children, which the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) will get you